# How to restrict WCF methods for specific Windows User Groups?

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service hosted in Windows Service, uses secure connection using https. There are two Windows User groups (say `Group A` and `Group B`) present on the same machine.

I need few methods can be called by `Group A` and a few by `Group B`.

And some methods by both.

I have used the `[PrincipalPermissionAttribute]` above the methods but it only takes the user role (i.e `Administrator` or `User` etc) not for user groups.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `ClientCredentialType = "Windows"` in your service configuration, then your "role" (defined in the `[PrincipalPermissionAttribute]`) **is** the Windows group.

See:

**WCF Security Guidance** by the MS Patterns & Practices group - topic on 
[How do I restrict access to WCF operations to specific Windows users?](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20do%20I%20restrict%20access%20to%20WCF%20operations%20to%20specific%20Windows%20users?)

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely check this out. BTW instead of mention the User Group name in all the method name, can it be possible to configure it?\